# How to use a spinner that does not expand, but just used to click on?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting this from googles calendar, hopefully you can see the image:

[image]

When looking specifically at the **From** and **To** parts, those look like `Spinner`s, but I could be completely wrong. I would like to do that, essentially what the Calendar in ICS does with `Spinner`s. I put the users date in it, then user clicks and a datepicker pops up. Problem is, I dont see anything that allows me to just set text in it. How can I set it to text without expanding? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to click on a button (or someother view) which opens a datepicker and then setting the date must change the button Text??

Comment: Yes @Archie.bpgc but I want to click on a `Spinner`. I have it working great using a `Button` and I could do the same for `TextView`'s, but the example I have above, which you can test yourself by using Google's native ICS calendar app, uses a `Spinner` just to display the date. I've been trying to keep it from expanding but I am not sure how to accomplish this. At this point I will abandon the idea, but now I am very curious how to make this work since I find no examples online.

Comment: @Andy: did you tried overriding the onTouch method by applying a onTouchListener, i guess that should work.

Comment: @JayshilDave Hmm. Good idea. Thanks. In either case it feels like overkill to have to set a spinner everytime. An alternative I've seen is setting the spinner style to a TextView which would be a lot less work. Thanks for the advice though :) I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't use a `Spinner`, but a `Button` that looks like a `Spinner`. Take a look to the [style.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar) files of the app.

Comment: Haha. Pretty late but thanks. I did some more digging before and found out it was a style too. Thanks though. Now there's an answer to accept :)